# How to host GitHub repo on Nimbella

Tags: nimbella-commander

How can I host my github repo on Nimbella .
I have created a website using HTML,CSS,JS. which I have hosted on GitHub pages. but I want to host it on Nimbella.

Comment: I don't know Nimbella, but it looks like they do have documentation for hosting static pages. Is the problem hosting static pages on Nimbella, or processing templates the same way as GitHub pages, or automatically updating your Nimbella hosting from GitHub changes, or something else? Or did you mean actually moving the git repo to Nimbella too, not just the hosted pages?

Comment: yeah got it they have documentation for hosting static pages https://nimbella.io/downloads/nim/nim.html#adding-static-web-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nimbella.io/downloads/nim/nim.html#adding-static-web-content

### **Adding static web content**

To add static web content to a project, add a directory called web as a peer of the directory called packages. This directory should contain files whose suffixes imply well-known mime types for web content, such as .html, .css, or .js.

**Note**: JavaScript files in static web content are not actions but are scripts intended to run in the browser.

The web directory can have subdirectories and can be built by website builders or other tools.

Like an action directory, the web directory may contain .include or .ignore to control what is actually considered web content, as opposed to build support or intermediate results. For more information about .include and .ignore, see Multifile actions created with autozip.

The web directory also supports integrated building, just like an action directory.

Here’s an example of a project with modest web content, populated by hand. For simplicity, the actions of the project are not shown.

```
example3/web/chatroom.html
example3/web/chatroom.css
example3/web/runner.js
example3/web/favicon.ico
```